# Delete files based on filename and if there are other files with a similar name

Tags: windows, cmd

Recently, a friend gave me his entire music collection, and I wanted to merge his collection with mine (using musicbrainz Picard) . But now I ended up with a lot of files, of which some are similar (like: "02 Skinny Love" and "02 Skinny Love 1" or "05 Lovers In Japan _ Reign Of Love" and "Coldplay - Lovers in Japan_Reign of Love")

And I was wondering if there is a smart way to filter out all duplicates and remove 1 of them, using the command line.

Note that almost all files have metadata which is exactly the same( so title: "Lovers in Japan / Reign of Love" is the same for both the files.

Comment: Have you tried just looking for an existing duplicate removal program? There shouldn't be any need to write one yourself, it's a common problem

Comment: Yes, there exists a way to do it using the command line: two nested `for` loops combined with testing `errorlevel` returned from  `fc /B "%%~fG" "%%~fg"` command… I can't claim it's the smartest way thought it should work…  [Take a look](http://ss64.com/nt/).